# AssertThat usage in a date comparison

Tags: java, assertj

I want to write a test against a search with date. I am thinking of a test code something like

```
assertThat(repository.findByBookingDateAfter(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1))).extracting("bookingDate").are(...));
```

where the class structure is something like the followings:

```
public class Booking{
  ...
  LocalDate bookingDate;
  ...
}
```

Because the query is on any bookings after a given date, my test shall check the field indeed later than the date. After some online search, I don't see any useful information. I am wondering whether I am on the right track or not.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Later, I change the dependency setup is the followings in the build.gradle file:

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
    exclude group: 'org.assertj'
}
testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.6.2'
```

to have the latest version of assertj.

**Update 2:**

The following is a screenshot of any methods starting with "is". The "isAfter" isn't on the list.

[image]

Comment: Could you please extend your example with more **code** and a description of what specifically you want to *test*, what you **expect** and what you already **tried**?
Depending on what **date api** you use (I see a `LocalDate` in your example) you might want to have a look at the documentation for [Joda-Time Assertion](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-joda-time.html) or the [code examples for Java 8 Date and Time API](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/Java8DateTimeAssertionsExamples.java).

Comment: Thanks. I add more details in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `allMatch` or `allSatisfy` assertions to check that every extracted date is after the one used in the query.

```
// set the extracted type to chain LocalDate assertion 
assertThat(result).extracting("bookingDate", LocalDate.class)
                  .allMatch(localDate -> localDate.isAfter(queryDate)));
```

or

```
// use a lambda to extract the LocalDate to chain LocalDate assertion
assertThat(result).extracting(Booking::getBookingDate)
                  .allSatisfy(localDate -> assertThat(localDate).isAfter(queryDate));
```

you get a better error message with the second assertion, it will show the faulty date.

Comment: Are allMatch and allSatisfy a part of assertj? I can't find them in any dependencies in my project. Also the localDate -> assertThat(localDate) code can't pass the compiler either.

Comment: they are in 3.6.2, see http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#method.summary

Comment: After replacing to the version, I can see allMatch and allSatisfy, but not isAfter. I scan over all available methods, but can't find a suitable one.

Comment: I can see it is in your code sample https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/DateAssertionsExamples.java , but I don't know why I can't see it.

Comment: you are looking at `Date` assertion examples instead of `LocalDate` that are shown in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/Java8DateTimeAssertionsExamples.java. 

Can you double check the AssertJ version you are using ?

Comment: I add the updated dependency setting of my project in the question. I find that I used Java6Assertions.assertThat instead of Assertions.assertThat. After making the correction, the problem still exists: can't find isAfter. I also try to something in the same fashion as allSatisfy(title -> assertThat(title).contains("the string")). The "contains" can't be found either.

Comment: The following example proves that `allSatisfy` works nicely with `LocalDate` `isAfter` assertion in assertj core 3.6.1: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/Java8DateTimeAssertionsExamples.java#L143

Check again the version that you are using. Show us how you get the assertj-core dependency.

Comment: you need to specify the the type of what you are extracting otherwise AssertJ, ex : https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java#L215    
Using Java8 I would recommend using a lambda to express the extraction operation as it would inform AssertJ of the extracted type,ex : https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java#L455.

hopefully this time it will work !

Comment: Yes, the change works for both cases. Thanks a lot for your help.